# Show formatted URL inside print method

Tags: javascript, apache-zeppelin

I want to create a table and in a "Link" column I want to add clickable URLs which should show a custom title as the URLs are too long.

Until now I have:

```
str = "Test Title";
link = str.link("https://my_long_url.com/v1.0/ui/index.html#/testkeywordreport?detailView=1&id=1234567")
```

As I'm inside a Apache Zeppelin paragraph I need to print contents in a table. So I create a table using the print method and add items to it in the same way, e.g.:

```
print("%table Test Link)
print(link)
```

Which results in a table like:

```
Test Link
---------
<a href="https://my_long_url.com/v1.0/ui/index.html#/testkeywordreport?detailView=1&id=1234567">Test Title</a>
```

What I expect is a hyperlink with the test title:

```
Test Link
---------
Test Title
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this using the **%html** tag in Apache Zeppelin:

```
str = "Test Title"
link =str.link("https://my_long_url.com/v1.0/ui/index.html#/testkeywordreport?detailView=1&id=1234567")
print("%table Test Link)
print("%html " + link)
```

[Reference: Apache Display System (Table)](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/latest/displaysystem/basicdisplaysystem.html#table)